# Changing child element style attributes inside ::after pseudoelement

Tags: html, css

I followed [this](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/11/pure-css-sticky-footers/) guide in order to position my footer at the bottom of the page. Here's how my HTML looks like:

```
<body>
<div class="page">
<header></header>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="leftA"></div>
<div class="rightA"></div>
</div>

<footer>
<p class="copyright">
</footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
footer, .wrapper::after {
                    display: block;
                    height: 9em;
                    clear: both;
                    width: 100%;
                    background-color: #808080;
                    border-radius: 0.3em;
                }
```

Before following the guide above I could change color, position and other attributes of this paragraph by using the following css:

```
p.copyright {
                    margin-left: 3em;
                    top: 5em;
                    left: 1em;
                    bottom: 0;
                    width: 25%;
                    color: white;
                    background-color: #808080;
                }
```

But now it no longer works. Let me know if you need additional data. Thanks!

Here's how Firefox "Inspect element" looks like (no styles applied other than inherited):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEXpo.png)

Comment: Please, define "no longer works" : could you provide a minimum complete and verifiable example and explain which is the expected result?

Comment: pseudo element need to have content so add this `content:" "`

Comment: It's also a terrible method of pushing the footer down. There are much better and dynamic methods of having a footer at the bottom of the page.

Comment: fcalderan, before incorporating the method of pushing the footer down, I could change attributes of the paragraph inside the footer by using p.copyright, now it no longer works. I've added a screenshot of Firefox element inspector to show that no class style is being applied by using p.copyright {}.

Comment: Temani, I added it but still no change when changing style for p.copyright {}.

Comment: Paulie_D, could you share a better method?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `"` in `<div class="rightA></div>`